# Spring Framework HttpRequestHandler failure

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

We have an application which communicates via REST requests made by clients.

The REST requests contain "region name" and a "ID" as parameters

So, a request would look something like this (for a DELETE)

```
http://host:port/regionnameID
```

These REST requests between regions in a federation are properly URL encoded

I find that these request fail if the region name has a slash ("/") in it.

Then, the request would look like so

```
http://host:port/region/nameID
```

This is due to incorrect interpretation of the Rest URL by HttpRequesthandler when there is a '/' in the region name.

Now, we have no control over clients sending REST request with "/" in the Region name.

Is there any method / configuration / workaround that can be done to prevent the HttpRequestHandler from returning 404

Comment: This is why this kind of REST-style URL isn't always suitable. When you have a wide variety of possible inputs, a query parameter is better.

Answer (score 1):

you should rewrite your urls with [urlrwrite](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) and use query parameters internal.

```
<rule>
 <name>Inbound:</name>
 <from>^(.*)ID$</from>
 <to last="true">delete?regionName=$1</to>
</rule>
```

Add your urlrewrite Filter in front of all other filters in web.xml

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a dirty problem. What I would try to do here is to use the Spring @RequestMapping annotation. There is some documentation on it here:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html

You can specific ant wildcards in the value you pass @RequestMapping. If you have a limited number of regions, then you can map them all to a single method as follows:
@RequestMapping(value={"/region1**","/region2**","/region3**")

In your controller method, you will have to add additional logical for parsing out the nameID.

If you have a large number of regions, I would then create a separate Spring Web app (servlet) just to handle these requests. That app would have a cached lookup table of regions.

Answer (score -1):

Configure your own handlerMapping bean (perhaps based on [AbstractUrlHandlerMapping](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.html))